# I want to repeat the contents of a title tag into the html document itself

Tags: php, html

I want to repeat the contents of a title tag into the html document itself. I can find info on how to extract html into the title tag, but not the other way around

I am hard coding a title tag set in the header of the html document and want to run server side,

```
<title>a title i want to repeat in html</title>
```

but below the header I want to be able to print that same content on my page within a text area. All I want to show is this...

a title i want to repeat in html

I cant find exactly how to do this. Something like this?

```
<?php echo $title;?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You will need to show your code for any type of specific answer.

Comment: I can find info on how to extract html into the title tag, but not the other way around

Comment: That's not code... And we need code. Your question is vague, for instance, how are you setting the title tag in the head of the document? Are you `echo`ing a variable or hard-coding the title? Are you trying to do this server-side (as your `php` tag would suggest) or are you looking to do this client-side?

Comment: I think you just need to spend some time playing around with the idea. `<title><?php echo $title;?></title>` in the head of the document should work, and you can just do the same thing in the body of the document: `<h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>`. This just requires you to set the `$title` variable before `echo`ing it.

Comment: Thanks so much - all I needed was
    
    <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>
    
I appreciate the help. - Mike

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're asking for but in javascript you can access the title with `document.title;`.

An example of how to set the title using javascript:

`<script type="text/javascript">
 document.title = "Something";
</script>`

An example of using javascript to edit html to the title:

**HTML**

`<div id="something"></div>`

**Javascript**

`<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = document.title;
</script>`
And since the php tag is on this question too:

`<?php echo $var; ?>`

That will print the variable "$var" onto the webpage.

Comment: That certainly sets the title tag to be "something" but what I am after is that the contents of the hard coded existing title tag to print out in plain text within a paragraph of text shown on the web page, Each version of what you have here changed the title tag in the header. I need it the other way around. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The second solution I listed uses javascript to get the title and place it into a tag with a certain id. So you could do <p>Some words, and my title <span id='titleplaceholder'></span></p> <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("titleplaceholder").innerHTML = document.title;</script>

Answer (score 1):

Best off using PHP:

```
<?php $title = 'a title i want to repeat in html' ?>

<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<?php echo $title; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this question is complete - I was able to do it with your help.
Mike